# Passing Variable from html form, google chart ajax request for json data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, google-visualization

I have tried searching around for a solution to my problem and I can't find any.

I wondered if anyone could help me out.

Basically I'm trying to let a user type in a variable so that they can see a google chart with the data they specifically request.

The chart is set up to do a ajax json request to another php script, though.

Here is my code. (I've deliberately left out the irrelevant code.)

HTML FORM,

```
<form id="form" action="http://localhost/query/CHART.php" method="POST">

  <div><label for="VARIABLE">Enter Variable or % For All Variables:
  <input type="text" name="VARIABLE" id="VARIABLE"/>
  </label>  
</div>
    <br />
    <div class="submit-button"><input type="submit" value="Get Data"/></div>

</form>
```

Google Chart PHP Page

```
 include "C:\wamp\www\includes\header.php";


<div id="content">
<br>

     <!--Load the AJAX API-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
          var jsonData = $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://localhost/query/MEAS.php",
              dataType:"json",
              async: false
              }).responseText;

          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

PHP JSON QUERY (MEAS.PHP)

```
  <?php


$conn = mysqli_connect('***', '***', '***');

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($conn, "TRACK")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}


$result = $conn->query("SELECT VARIABLE, var1, var2, var3, var4 FROM MEASTEST WHERE VARIABLE LIKE '$VARIABLE'
");    
// creates column nsmes, nothing to do with query //  
    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
    array('id' => "", 'label' => 'VARIABLE', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'string'),
    array('id' => "", 'label' => 'VAR1', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number'),
    array('id' => "", 'label' => 'VAR2', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number'),
    array('id' => "", 'label' => 'VAR3', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number'),
    array('id' => "", 'label' => 'VAR4', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number'),


    );
    $rows = array();
    while ($nt = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => $nt['VARIABLE'], 'f' =>NULL);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $nt['VAR1'], 'f' =>NULL);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $nt['VAR2'], 'f' =>NULL);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $nt['VAR3'], 'f' =>NULL);
    $temp[] = array('v' => $nt['VAR4'], 'f' =>NULL);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }
    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
    echo $jsonTable;




if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}


?>
```

The result is that the google chart page doesn't load the chart up, due to the variable not being passed to the query and no json data coming back into the page.

Hope this makes sense!

EDIT: I did delibrately leave code out when posting but its confused people, the full php page is there now.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**. Have a look at **[pdo / prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)**

Comment: That looks pretty complicated, I'm brand new to php, is this the only way to do what im trying to acheive?

Comment: DannyEng14, The links I provided don't necessarily answer your question. I'm just trying to say that the way you're accessing the database is _very_ dangerous. It's basically in invitation for someone to mess with your DB.

Answer (score 2):

edited:

Your Code Is Not Light, You send Ajax request To "MEAS.php" ??

which Is "MEAS.php"'s Code ??

if "MEAS.php" is:

```
<?php
$VARIABLE = $_POST['VARIABLE'];

$conn = blah,blah

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($conn, "TRACK")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}


$result = $conn->query("SELECT VARIABLE FROM MEASTEST WHERE VARIABLE LIKE '$VARIABLE'
");
```

You Must Set Response "Content-type" with header function:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json")
```

and return a json:

```
echo json_encode(" your Response Data ")
```

Comment: Edited now, don't know how that was missing

Comment: Tried putting the header in and still the same, this chart works perfectly when I request a specific variable in the php file myself. It's something to do with the variable not passing from the html form > chart page > to the php file, and back

Answer (score -1):

Your AJAX request is not sending any parameters:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/query/MEAS.php",
    dataType:"json",
    async: false
}).responseText;
```

you need to add the parameter to the request:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/query/MEAS.php",
    data: {
        myParameterName: parameterValue
    },
    dataType:"json",
    async: false
}).responseText;
```

If this is happening in response to user input, then the drawing should happen inside an event handler in response to whatever needs to trigger the redraw.  As an example:

```
function drawChart() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/query/MEAS.php",
        data: {
            myParameterName: 'default value'
        },
        dataType:"json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    // create and draw the chart
    // ...

    /* assumes you have:
     *     a chart object called "chart"
     *     an options object called "options"
     *     a button with the id "myButton" that should trigger a redraw on click
     *     an input field "myInput" that has the value you want to send to your server
     */
    function updateChart () {
        jsonData = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/query/MEAS.php",
            data: {
                myParameterName: document.querySelector('#myInput').value
            },
            dataType:"json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    var btn = document.querySelector('#myButton');
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        btn.addEventListener('click', updateChart);
    }
    else if (document.attachEvent) {
        btn.attachEvent('onclick', updateChart);
    }
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```